# High data rate detected but slow speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, adsl

I have an ADSL2+ modem and my max download speed tends to be ~170kb/s (1300 kbps), instead my modem stats claim that it should be almost 5x faster:

```
                     Downstream  Upstream 
SNR Margin (dB) :    12.5 db     15.0 db    
Attenuation (dB) :   32.5 db     17.0 db    
Data Rate :          6784 kbps   480 kbps
```

I have the same problem with all my computers, therefore I'm pretty sure it's not about TCP settings.

-- edit: --

All the computers are connected via WiFi. I've tried to change the channel and connect a single pc but (even with a cable connection) the download speed remains the same. The computers have different operating systems (Windows XP, 7 and MacOSX 10.8). I've tried at 02:00 A.M. yesterday and the speed was still stuck at 170KB/s!

Comment: Have you spoken to your ISP as they could be throttling your data rates if you have gone over their usage cap.  Is this all the time?  How many machines?  Are they all the same operating system?  Are some connected via wires or are they all connected via wireless?  If they are wireless have you tried changing the Wifi channel? Have you tried with only one machine on the network at a time?  If there are multiple people with machines on the network have you made sure none of them are running bittorrent or large downloads?  Please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: @Mokubai I've updated my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you've pretty much tried everything I would have and your machines are disparate enough to rule out problems with them which really just leaves your router or ISP as the source of the problem.  Given you router is reporting a good connection I would suspect your ISP is limiting your for some reason and contact them.  Some ISPs limit you on how much you download in a month, others by how much you download in a day...